# SoapUI - Removing timestamp from the script log

Tags: groovy, soapui

Is it possible to remove the time stamp from the script log in SoapUI? I am printing maybe important information there and the time stamp makes it look really messy. Tabbing and creating new lines using escape sequences do not properly format text in the script log so this approach is not possible

Comment: I have tried looking up changing different color fonts(which the developers stated was in their backlog in 2010, seen no updates to this), going through the SoapUI preferences under Tools, UI settings, and font settings for font color and removal of timestamp.

Comment: @LinhSaysHi, what actually do you need or trying to achieve? It is very important to have timestamp in the logging especially to know what is happening / dealing with multi threaded applications /  to know where it is spending time intervals etc. If you want, you may try with `println` instead of `log.info` (or so) which will be logged plainly without timestamp.

Comment: I am just logging information that is related to the id I am searching for. For example, I have an id and I am searching for that particular id in the xml file. When the id is found, it will log the id and related information such as first name, last name, etc. The reason I did not like println because it doesn't show anywhere in SoapUI

Comment: @LinhSaysHi, start soapUI using command prompt - SOAPUI_HOME/bin/soapui.bat or .sh (depending on platform) - you should be able to see on the console what you print.

Answer (score 1):

SoapUI, out of the box, **cannot turn off the timestamp** in logs. This is a feature provided by [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/), which SoapUI utilizes for writing the logs. Further, this feature is highly desirable for searching relevant information from the logs.

One option is to create / utilize a script mechanism of your own, which logs only information that is relevant to you. Possibly just dumping relevant information into a .csv file, and then port-processing that with something like Excel.

Alternatively, you could use a tool such as `awk` (or any scripting language, even Groovy) to post-process the log file, extracting only the information that is relevant to you.